# What is the correct way to use getInitialProps with getDefaultProps (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react component you can have both functions as shown below.

```
  getInitialProps() {
    return fetchProps();
  };
  getDefaultProps() {
    return this.defaultProps;
  }
```

Can **getDefaultProps** ever be called in the react lifecycle?

I'd imagine you'd want to do some try catch in **getInitialProps** that grabs the **defaultProps** whenever it fails to **fetchProps**:

```
  getInitialProps() {
    try{
      return fetchProps();
    } catch(error){
      return getDefaultProps();
    }
  };
```

Seems strange to me.

Comment: What's the use for getInitialProps? What's fetchProps? Is it supposed to replace props that were passed to the component? This may be XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know getInitialProps() is used for async behavior while getDefaultProps() is more for setting up the props for a component so it can still render before the props are passed.

So to answer your question I dont think so. you cannot call getDefaultProps() once it is rendered.

This would be an example of using getInitialProps()

```
Page.getInitialProps = () => {
  return fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/developit/preact')
    .then(res => res.json())
}
```

While getDefaultProps() would work more like this

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
return {
  name: 'Mary'
};
```